# How do I disable the keyboard shortcuts in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with some event handling in matplotlib. Specifically 'key_press_event's. But the predefined keyboard shortcuts are getting in my way. Is there a way to turn these off?

They say I can override the keys by use of: "matplotlibrc (#keymap.*)". But I don't understand what they're referring to and I haven't found any further explanation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can modify in `plt.rcParams` dictionary.  Example, to disable the "s" keyboard shortcut for the "save figure" button:

```
>>> plt.rcParams['keymap.save']
['s', 'ctrl+s']
>>> plt.rcParams['keymap.save'].remove('s')
```

If you want the changes to apply globally/permanently, then edit in the `matplotlibrc` file and restart the Python interpreter.  You may find the location of the config file on your system by calling a helper function:

```
>>> matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
'/Users/wim/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc'
```

*Note: In older versions of matplotlib, the keymap bindings were strings rather than lists. If you are stuck on older version, you could set the value to an empty string rather than calling remove.*

Comment: worked perfectly. It's obvious, but I'll just add that `>>> plt.rcParams` gives the full list of the names that can be changed. thanks for your help

Comment: There's also: plt.rcParamsDefault

Comment: It seems that it in the current version of Matplotlib (3.1.1), the value stored in the dictionary under `'keymap.save'` is no longer a string but a list of strings `['s', 'ctrl+s']`, to allow multiple keys for the same action. So instead of setting it to an empty string, you should remove the unwanted key from the list: `plt.rcParams['keymap.save'].remove('s')`

Comment: @BasSwinckels  Thanks for the comment, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

See https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html for all keymap keywords that you can use with the above mentioned method, **plt.rcParams['keymap.*']**

---

I was asked by Review to include the essential parts of my answer besides the reference link, and rightly so. However, in this specific case the list of all the *plt.rcParams* contains 316 items and it will be silly to include them in here.
So what I can do is give you the updated **official** Matplotlib link --which the one I provided above redirects to-- where you can find them, if you need:  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html

(It is still a link that may change after some time, but since it is official, you will always find your way to the list in question. )

Comment: This is a useful addition to the above answer. Here I found the keymap.<word> necessary to disable the shortcut.

Comment: You are generally right. But in this case I provided an **official** Matplotlib link. URLs in such links may change with time but they usually if not alwyays redirect to the updated ones --if the company still exists, of course-- as in the present case.  Anyway, I edited my answer, but in this particular case I could not provide the "essential parts" you have mentioned.(See why in the edited section.)